# "Question feed" brings up raw html and not feed

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

The "Question Feed" button that can be found on the right-hand side of the page (under "Hot Network Questions"). When I click on this is loads up https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/. However, on Chrome, it appears to load up the raw HTML for this and does not display the questions. Like this:
[image]

I have tried this on IE and it appears to load correctly. This is how loads on IE:
[image]

Has anyone had this problem before and what I can do to be able to get this link to work correctly.

Comment: Interesting... if you try to open the page in Firefox, you get a ["What should Firefox do with this file?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jRJG.png) dialog

Comment: It's not "raw HTML" it's XML (it has the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` processing instruction at the top). It's meant to be used in a feed reader. IE has built-in stylehseets to convert feed XML to a nice HTML presentation; other browsers don't. Hardly a bug.

Comment: Not just XML, it's RSS. All browsers used to have a built-in RSS reader, but Chrome and Firefox dropped them. Chrome has chosen for the weird _just display the code_ solution while Firefox asks you which RSS reader to use. There are plenty RSS readers, some plug directly into the browser.